# Double integral with polar?

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, polar-coordinates

I have the following integral :

$$\iint\limits_R \operatorname e^{-\frac{x^2+y^2}{2}} \operatorname d\!y \operatorname d\!x $$

Where R is:
$$R=\{(x,y):x^2+y^2 \leq 1\}$$

I think I should convert to polar in order to solve it. Is this correct? Also how do you calculate the integration limits?  Thanks

Comment: If you draw a picture of $R$ you should easily be able to read off the possible values of $r$ and $\theta$.

Answer (score 1):

Set $x=r\cos(t)$ and $y=r\sin(t)$. We then have
\begin{align}
\iint_R e^{-(x^2+y^2)/2}dydx &= \int_{0}^{2\pi} \int_{r=0}^1 e^{-r^2/2}rdrdt = 2\pi \int_0^1 e^{-r^2/2} d(r^2/2)\\
& = 2\pi \int_0^{1/2}e^{-t}dt = 2\pi (1-e^{-1/2})
\end{align}

Comment: thank you for your help. Im getting 2(1-(1/sqrt(e)))pi is this correct?

Comment: @Kevin94 Yes. It is same as what I have written.

Answer (score 1):

$R=\{(r,\theta):0\leq r\leq 1,0\leq \theta \leq 2\pi\}$
\begin{align*}
\iint_Re^{-\frac{x^2+y^2}{2}}\mathrm dx\mathrm dy&=\int_{\theta = 0}^{\theta=2\pi}\left[\int_{r=0}^{r=1}e^{-\frac{1}{2}r^2}r\mathrm dr\right]\mathrm d\theta
\end{align*}

Comment: thank @Mario G  for your help. Im getting 2(1-(1/sqrt(e)))pi is this correct?